# How to specify image platform in gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to build CI pipeline which does build for particular image. In the CI file however, I could not find a way to specify image platform.

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build_j:
  image: customServer/debian/jessy
```

I checked [Docker Images doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html) and [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/#container-registry-examples-with-gitlab-cicd) but could not find any example. Alternative way perhaps is to pull image explicitly and run commands using script.

```
docker pull debian:jessy -platform i386
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since multi architecture/platform tags of a Docker image have different **digests**, You can [pull a Docker image using its digest](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#pull-an-image-by-digest-immutable-identifier) (instead of using tags) to pull the desired architecture/platform.

Here is an example of multi architecture/platform tag of a Docker image (Ubuntu) in [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu?tab=tags):
[image]
As you can see, **20.04** is a multi architecture tag and there are different digests for each of architectures in the tag. 
If you run command `docker pull ubuntu:20.04`
it will pull all architectures.
But command 
`docker pull ubuntu@sha256:55e5613c8c7bcd8044aaf09d64d20518964a0d7a6e41af129f95b731301c2659`
will pull just `linux/arm/v7`.

As I tried, it is possible to use digest in `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yml
job_1:
  image: ubuntu@sha256:55e5613c8c7bcd8044aaf09d64d20518964a0d7a6e41af129f95b731301c2659
  script:
    - ...

job_2:
  image: alpine@sha256:71465c7d45a086a2181ce33bb47f7eaef5c233eace65704da0c5e5454a79cee5
  script:
    - ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Speaking of image digest, [GitLab 13.5](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/10/22/gitlab-13-5-released/#create-release-with-image-digest-on-new-tag) (October 2020) proposes:

> ### Create release with image digest on new tag
>
> Docker supports immutable image identifiers and we have adopted this best practice to update our cloud-deploy images.
>
> When a new image is tagged, we also programmatically retrieve the image digest upon its build, and create a release note to effectively communicate this digest to users.
> This guarantees that every instance of the service runs exactly the same code.
> You can roll back to an earlier version of the image, even if that version wasn’t tagged (or is no longer tagged). This can even prevent race conditions if a new image is pushed while a deploy is in progress.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_5/digest.png -- Create release with image digest on new tag]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/cloud_deployment/) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/207379).