# docker pull with platform option is not pulling the correct architecture image

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, oraclelinux

I wanted to download docker images of oraclelinux for amd64 and arm64 architectures. But both are showing same sha256 digest. Why is that?

```
docker pull --platform=linux/amd64 oraclelinux:7-slim
Trying to pull repository docker.io/library/oraclelinux ...
7-slim: Pulling from docker.io/library/oraclelinux
Digest: sha256:7a46c0134e2cad2d15a98eac50c89f9e0f4640c0461b838672d41ea0710d75c5
Status: Downloaded newer image for oraclelinux:7-slim
oraclelinux:7-slim
```

```
docker pull --platform=linux/arm64 oraclelinux:7-slim
Trying to pull repository docker.io/library/oraclelinux ...
7-slim: Pulling from docker.io/library/oraclelinux
Digest: sha256:7a46c0134e2cad2d15a98eac50c89f9e0f4640c0461b838672d41ea0710d75c5
Status: Downloaded newer image for oraclelinux:7-slim
oraclelinux:7-slim
```

I wanted to use both separately in Gitlab CI-CD as mentioned in [How to specify image platform in gitlab-ci.yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63833973/how-to-specify-image-platform-in-gitlab-ci-yml) .
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The digest listed by docker is the manifest list. It will be dereferenced to the platform specific manifest as the image is pulled, but docker lists the manifest list for portability (the same digest can be used other multiple platforms).

```
$ regctl manifest get oraclelinux:7-slim
Name:        oraclelinux:7-slim
MediaType:   application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json
Digest:      sha256:7a46c0134e2cad2d15a98eac50c89f9e0f4640c0461b838672d41ea0710d75c5
             
Manifests:   
             
  Name:      docker.io/library/oraclelinux:7-slim@sha256:eccab04a8a5299ea5ae6cc51ad697aa01012ff2732c999360c4d218dd9451440
  Digest:    sha256:eccab04a8a5299ea5ae6cc51ad697aa01012ff2732c999360c4d218dd9451440
  MediaType: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json
  Platform:  linux/amd64
             
  Name:      docker.io/library/oraclelinux:7-slim@sha256:fd4d966f65ddc0ac1727570766563e2f9d0dd8e2557234d179a017e244e67979
  Digest:    sha256:fd4d966f65ddc0ac1727570766563e2f9d0dd8e2557234d179a017e244e67979
  MediaType: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json
  Platform:  linux/arm64
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. But somehow I am getting below error -> ```docker run -it oraclelinux:7-slim@sha256:fd4d966f65ddc0ac1727570766563e2f9d0dd8e2557234d179a017e244e67979
exec /bin/bash: exec format error```

Comment: Is your x86 host configured with an interpreter in the kernel to run binaries for another platform like arm64? Docker configures qemu's binfmt_misc on Docker Desktop.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @BMitch this `sha256` is from the manifest list, which contains all architectures.

Since multi architecture/platform tags of a Docker image have different **digests**, You can [pull a Docker image using its digest](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#pull-an-image-by-digest-immutable-identifier) (instead of using tags) to pull the desired architecture/platform.

As we can see in [oraclelinux](https://hub.docker.com/layers/oraclelinux/library/oraclelinux/7-slim/images/sha256-fd4d966f65ddc0ac1727570766563e2f9d0dd8e2557234d179a017e244e67979?context=explore) -- The `sha256` from `arm64` is `fd4d966f65ddc0ac1727570766563e2f9d0dd8e2557234d179a017e244e67979` So you can pull this image by running:

```
$ docker pull oraclelinux@sha256:fd4d966f65ddc0ac1727570766563e2f9d0dd8e2557234d179a017e244e67979
```

But it looks like the `oraclelinux` has another [repository](https://hub.docker.com/r/arm64v8/oraclelinux/tags) to store `arm64` images, so maybe you can run:

```
$ docker pull oraclelinux:7-slim
$ docker pull arm64v8/oraclelinux:7-slim
```

Does it work for you?

Comment: This is handy and better than the digest. But I get below error -> ```docker run -it arm64v8/oraclelinux:7-slim bash
exec /usr/bin/bash: exec format error```

Comment: `exec format error` means that a binary is built for another architecture than your system.

Answer (score 0):

Add before_script

- export IMAGE_NAME
- export IMAGE_TAG

Then
script

- docker pull $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG

Adjust this to suit best for you.

I pulled both.
diff can help you.

```
diff <(docker inspect 6b9fd09833be) <(docker inspect 554de8d676bd)
```

Comment: The question is - why the sha256 digest is same for different platforms and if they have to be same then how I can download the image directly using sha256 digest for respective platform

Comment: You are downloading the same image, the `sha256` will be the same in that case.

Comment: @JuanFontes I have specified different platform, amd64 vs arm64

Comment: @dganesh2002 got it. I've added an answer, let me know if it helps.